# how to trigger a mail based on first shell echo result?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

i have two shell scripts, one is checking_file.sh, second one is mailing.sh.

`checking_file.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

filepath="/home/documents/hello.txt"

if [ -f "$filepath" ]; then
   echo "file exists"
else
   echo "file not exists"

fi
```

`mailing.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(/home/documents/checking_file.sh)

if [ "$output" = "file not exists" ]; then
   echo "trigger mail to developer"
else
  echo "file is available in time no mail needed"
fi
```

> mailing.sh should execute at last. both are different scripts.
>
> i used chmod u+r+X /home/documents/checking_file.sh in mailing.sh, but mailing.sh should execute last.
> mailing.sh should read the checking_file.sh, its should not execute
> checking_file.sh shell

Comment: Your question is confusing (for me). Your code should work fine. just run `/path/to/mailing.sh` and it will run the `checking_file.sh` and your results will be as you expect. I think there are simpler ways to accomplish what you are doing, but I'm assuming there is a reason you have structured your question this way. Good luck.

Comment: Consider using exit statuses, not text output, to determine if an email should be sent or not.

Comment: `mailing.sh` *should* execute first: *it* executes `checking_file.sh`, then uses the result (or as I suggested, the exit status) to decide what to do next.

Comment: I'm don't want execute again checking_file.sh(first running) while running mailing.sh(running last). just i want to use the echo result of the of the checking_file.sh. here i needed to use chmod? how i use exit status here?

Comment: I'm don't want to execute mailing.sh first. the mailing.sh just  read the checking_file.sh echo result. its possible here?

Comment: sounds like you need to modify `checking_file.sh` to write its message to a file, then have `maling.sh` read that file (and perhaps add some logic to verify the file exists and/or has been updated 'recently'; then perhaps (re)move the file once it's been processed if simply to keep `mailing.sh` from processing it again)

Comment: Yes, mailing.sh should read the output of checking_file.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OP's comments:

- `mailing.sh` should not call `checking_file.sh` but should 'read' the output from `checking_file.sh`
- one approach would be to have `checking_file.sh` write its output to a file ...
- modify `checking_file.sh` to write its output to a file
- modify `mailing.sh` to read the contents of said file

Making minimal changes to OP's current code:

```
$ cat checking_file.sh
#!/bin/bash

filepath="/home/documents/hello.txt"

if [ -f "$filepath" ]; then
   echo "file exists"
else
   echo "file not exists"
fi > /home/documents/checking_file.out               # write output to file



$ cat mailing.sh
#!/bin/bash

#output=$(/home/documents/checking_file.sh)
output=$(cat /home/documents/checking_file.out)      # read output from file

if [ "$output" = "file not exists" ]; then
   echo "trigger mail to developer"
else
   echo "file is available in time no mail needed"
fi
```

**NOTES:**

- OP may want to add some logic to `mailing.sh` to verify `checking_file.out` actually exists
- OP may want to add some logic to `mailing.sh` to remove/rename `checking_file.out` so that a repeated run of `mailing.sh` does not process the same `checking_file.out` a second time

---

Addressing OP's comment/question about not modifying `checking_file.sh` ...

With no modifications to `checking_file.sh` we can have the invocation direct all output to a file, eg:

```
$ /home/documents/checking_file.sh > /home/documents/checking_file.out 2>&1
```

Comment: is possible without modified the checking_file.sh?

Comment: @ragdev updated the answer with one approach that does not require modifying `checking_file.sh`